# Insert rows according to value of columns in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering the following dataframe in pandas

```
   date     action    price     
  20150101   buy       10
  20150102   buy       9
  20150103   sell      11
  20150104   sell      10
  20150105   buy       8
  20150106   sell      9
```

If I want to add rows whenever 'sell' turn in to 'buy', and inserted row is just the copy of previous row except changing 'sell' into 'buy' such as follows:

```
   date     action    price     
  20150101   buy       10
  20150102   buy       9
  20150103   sell      11
  20150104   sell      10
**20150104   buy       10**
  20150105   buy       8
  20150106   sell      9
**20150106   buy       9 **
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could identify the transition rows using

```
mask = (df['action'] == 'sell') & (df['action'].shift(-1) != 'sell')
# In [229]: mask
# Out[229]: 
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2    False
# 3     True
# 4    False
# 5     True
# Name: action, dtype: bool
```

Then you could make a new DataFrame, consisting of the rows where `mask` is True:

```
new = df.loc[mask].copy()
```

Set the action to `'buy'`:

```
new['action'] = 'buy'
#        date action  price
# 3  20150104    buy     10
# 5  20150106    buy      9
```

Build a new DataFrame which concatentates `df` and `new`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, new])
```

and sort by `date`:

```
df = df.sort(['date'])
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
mask = (df['action'] == 'sell') & (df['action'].shift(-1) != 'sell')
new = df.loc[mask].copy()
new['action'] = 'buy'
df = pd.concat([df, new])
df = df.sort(['date'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

yields

```
       date action  price
0  20150101    buy     10
1  20150102    buy      9
2  20150103   sell     11
3  20150104   sell     10
4  20150104    buy     10
5  20150105    buy      8
6  20150106   sell      9
7  20150106    buy      9
```